# sql query not working with order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Here is my original query that works

```
 Select * FROM story st, sentences s, speaker sp 
 WHERE (st.lesson_id = '1' AND 
        st.speaker_id = sp.speaker_id AND 
        st.sentence_id = s.sentence_id)
```

When I try to add a Order By it breaks down.

```
 Select * FROM story st, sentences s, speaker sp 
 WHERE (st.lesson_id = '1' AND 
        st.speaker_id = sp.speaker_id AND 
        st.sentence_id = s.sentence_id) ORDER BY st.story_in_lesson_id ASC
```

Can't figure out why it is breaking.

EDIT:
Here is the error I get Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object()

EDIT:
My PHP code

```
$result = $mysqli->query("Select * FROM story st, sentences s, speaker sp 
                         WHERE st.lesson_id = '1' AND 
                         st.speaker_id = sp.speaker_id AND 
                         st.sentence_id = s.sentence_id 
                         ORDER BY st.story_in_lesson_id ASC");

while ($value = $result->fetch_object()) { 
    //never goes in here fails at the fetch_object()
}
```

EDIT:

Is it possible that it does not work because I am trying to query multiple tables? Only one of the tables has the story_in_lesson_id which is the story table. When I run the query just on that table it works find.

EDIT:

More info, copied the DB over to my work Mac and the query works!!! But why does it not work on my computer?? By the way I am strictly testing the query now by just running it inside Sequel Pro.

Comment: how does it break, any errors..?

Comment: You don't need parenthesis around the where clauses

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object()

Comment: show your PHP code having fetch_object() pls

Comment: Do you have `column st.story_in_lesson_id` in you `table`?

Comment: @RohanKumar yes it is in the table, it is the the story table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help! I have solved the issue!!!

In the end it ended up being a file writing permissions issue. I figured it out by running my query in Sequel Pro which threw a error about some file located at /var/folders/41/some big number/T/ . I went to the dir and allowed for write access tried the query in Sequel Pro and it worked. Then I go to my php and try it there and it worked.

If anyone can answer why this happened? Do all queries write to a log file or anything like that?  If anyone can share some more inside.

Answer (score 3):

Please remove your where condition dear ..... may be it's working and please give me reply what you getting result .

```
SELECT * 
FROM   story st 
       INNER JOIN sentences s 
               ON st.sentence_id = s.sentence_id 
       INNER JOIN speaker sp 
               ON st.speaker_id = sp.speaker_id 
ORDER  BY st.story_in_lesson_id ASC
```

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: you remove where condition

Comment: Yea I removed the where condition and it does not work, I remove the ORDER BY and it does work, I remove the ORDER BY and add the WHERE condition and it works. Its sooooo strange, the story table has story_in_lesson_id I am able to print it in my while loop when I dont use the ORDER BY statement

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `st.story_in_lesson_id` exists in your `story table`
and to prevent from `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object()` you should try it like,

```
$query = "Select * FROM story st, sentences s, speaker sp 
              WHERE st.lesson_id = '1' AND 
              st.speaker_id = sp.speaker_id AND 
              st.sentence_id = s.sentence_id 
              ORDER BY st.story_in_lesson_id ASC";
              // check story_in_lesson_id exists in story table 

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($value = $result->fetch_object()) { 
       // while code
    } // while ends
} // if result ends
```

Comment: This just catches the error for me, but in my test scenario I have story_in_lesson_id so it should work but it does not.

Comment: Maybe there is no row in story that has a corresponding row in BOTH speaker and sentences

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM story st
INNER JOIN sentences s ON st.sentence_id = s.sentence_id
INNER JOIN speaker sp ON st.speaker_id = sp.speaker_id
WHERE st.lesson_id = '1' 
ORDER BY st.story_in_lesson_id ASC
```